# What is the usage of javascript scrollTimeout?

Tags: javascript, web, scroll, window

I just encounter `scrollTimeout` and couldn't figure the usage of it, I can't find any useful result in Google too! isn't there any refernece for all javascript functions ?

Comment: you encountered it where? My guess is it is part of a script. Show the code.

Comment: from the console (ctrl+shift+j) in google chrome, while I was checking this site `http://www.solutionstudios.com/` when you type `scroll` you will see the auto complete shows scrollTimeout..... oops, it seems to be something special to this site :p sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) returns an id, they check to see if it is still active and cancel it.

```
var onScrollVisitorsBlock = function () {
        clearTimeout(scrollTimeout);
        scrollTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
        ....
```

This way, the function is not continuously executing.